In python how to share a large data structure across modules (no copies)
I am working on a prject where I use a Pandas dataframe, rather large, and I need to let several functions access it.
So far I have used a single python script, where I create the dataframe as global to the script, and then define the various functions, which read and write from/to it.
So far, so good.
Now, the project is growing, and so is the number of functions, and I would like to split the project into several files (modules).
The first idea is to let the dataframe to be global across the modules, and I have found some info on how to do it (I would still appreciate a comment on which is the best/most pythonic/most efficient way).
However, I have rad that this is frown upon.
So, what would be the best approach, taking into account that the dataframe can become quite large, so that making a copy local to each function, when called, would be inefficient?
Thanks!

Not sure, if I understand correctly, but it sounds like this discussion might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665461/the-efficiency-when-using-a-big-data-structure-in-a-function-in-python

Is it possible that you create a Class and initialize it with the dataframe object or read the database in the class __init__ function; and add the functions which access the object as member functions to the same class?

Thanks! I appreciate your idea. For the time being I would avoid object oriented programming.
